# Chain guards for front derailleurs: Metal alternative to SKS chainboard?

Tags: chain, derailleur

Can anyone recommend an aftermarket, front-derailleur-compatible chainguard (along the lines of the [SKS chainboard](http://www.sks-germany.com/?l=en&a=products&r=chainguards)) that's **not** made of plastic? Maybe something like the one on the [Marin Bridgeway triple](http://www.marinbikes.com/2013/bike_specs.php?serialnum=2076&Bridgeway_Triple)?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Unfortunately, this isn't necessarily the best site for specific product recommendations. That's because every different recommendation is equally valid and subject to individual preferences.

Comment: Hmm, I can see how that's an issue for "What's the best [some common component]"-type questions, but what I'm looking for here isn't a preference, but rather any concrete example(s) of a product that meets specific, non-subjective criteria, i.e. (1) is a chainguard (2) works with a front derailleur (3) is made of metal. That said, thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it exist over the shelf.  It's already hard to find one that's made of plastic.  If you really are set on going metal I'd suggest keeping a single chain ring and focus your gearing in the rear (hub, cassette, or hub+cassette combo).  Building a custom chain guard will be costly, a pain, and not guaranteed to be a success.  If you really want to have some gearing in front you could look at the [SchlumpfDrive](http://www.haberstock-mobility.com) but at these prices you could also just get a [Rohloff](http://www.rohloff.de/en/).  Both should work fine with the standard metal chain guards.

Comment: Ha. Pretty awesome, but at those prices I'd probably be as well off either (1) taking a metal shop class or (2) buying a second bike.